# Finding critical points of a function that is bounded by a condition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got stuck trying to solve a critical points calculation problem of the following function :

f(x,y)=3x−y

Thing is, I calculated the partial derivatives and came up with no results for any critical points.
The function is bounded by the following term:

x^2+2y^2=38

which I immediately assumed was the equation of an ellipse, and tried to bound the 'x' and the 'y' in the original function by the ellipse's 'a' and 'b' values.

I think I got utterly lost in the process of solving this problem, help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try Lagrange Multiplier method?

Comment: This problem was given in a Calculus university course, we haven't learned about that method yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,y) = 3x-y$

Given constraint is $x = \sqrt{38 - 2y^2}$

$f(x,y) = 3\sqrt{38 - 2y^2} - y$

Now at critical points, $ \, \, \frac{-6y}{\sqrt{38-2y^2}} - 1 = 0$ (taking derivative and equating to zero)

So $y = \pm1$ and now you can find values of $x$ from the constraint and complete the solution.